# Solving a Segmentation Fault on UVA OJ

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

Below is a code which is quite basic, using `std::sort` and a custom comparator function to sort the input data.

The comparator however, requires a value from the input which is not part of the data, namely the `m` variable below.

When I ran the code against an online judge, I got a Runtime Error -- Segmentation Fault.

I would like to know what could have cause this, or how to debug this as I am running out of ideas. Thanks in advance.

The problem is [here](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=2296).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int m;

bool cmp(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    vector<int> num;
    int input;
    while(cin >> n >> m)
    {
        if(n == 0 && m == 0)        
        {
            cout << "0 0" << endl;
            break;
        }           
        for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            cin >> input;
            num.push_back(input);
        }
        sort(num.begin(),num.end(),cmp);
        cout << n << " " << m << endl;
        for(i = 0; i < num.size(); ++i)
        {
            cout << num[i] << endl;
        }
        num.clear();        
    }
    return 0;
}

bool cmp(int a, int b)
{    
    if(a%m > b%m)
        return 0;
    else if(a%m < b%m)
        return 1;
    else  //a%m == b%m
    {
        if(a%2 == 0 && b%2 == 0)
        {
            if(a < b)
                return 1;
            else return 0;
        } 
        else if(a%2 == 0 && b%2 != 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }   
        else if(a%2 != 0 && b%2 == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(a < b)
                return 0;
            else return 1;
        } 
    }    
}
```

Comment: If you give a down vote, at least leave a comment.

Comment: Have you tried running this in a debugger?  Are you saying that you can't replicate the crash yourself?

Comment: Well the thing with Online Judge is you don't usually know why it's wrong. I can run it without any problem with the example given by the problem. Simply put, no, I can't replicate it myself.

Comment: This is actually my friend's code, my code works okay with similar logic. There's really no logic here anyway.

Comment: cmp isn't a strict weak ordering. Consider m=1, a=b=1.

Comment: Why are you returning `0` and `1` instead of `true` or `false`?

Comment: Regardless, T.C.'s comment explains the crash.  The function `cmp` is invalid for `std::sort`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Like I said, it's not my own code. But he switched from C, that might be the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cmp function is not conform to the criteria of strict weak orderings (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). The criterion of irreflexivity (i.e. cmp(x,x) has to evaluate as false) is violated.

For any odd x cmp(x,x) will evaluate as true. You might want to change the two return statements in the innermost else-clause:

```
else {
    if(a < b) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

or shorter:

```
else {
    return a < b;
}
```

In this form irreflexivity is guaranteed. The other criteria should also be valid from what I see so far.

Comment: I see. I have also suspected it's a problem with my comparator function. However, I cannot see why this can cause a segmentation fault as I always thought that is memory-related.

Comment: Being stuck in an infinite loop may also cause a segmentation fault (though I'm not sure why, it happened to me several times but when I try to induce it artificially, it doesn't work; I guess it happens if there's a lot of memory addressed within this loop). In the previous form of cmp this could happen if the sort algorithm wants to swap two neighbouring elements of the same value (since after the swap they will still be neighbouring and still have the same value).